# Sliding menu with a blurred background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've created a slide menu that has a blurred background, it works ok when it's just a static image but when using it with a slideshow it shows the wrong image.

Please see attached fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/H863X/2/

When you click the red box, the menu will slide out and the menu background will be blurred, this is because it's inherited the image from the id #hero-container, and added a blur.

Now if you click on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/H863X/1/

You'll notice the image has been replaced with a black image, but if you click the red button the slide will still show the original image, this is because it's still inheriting the image from the id #hero-container, see the following code for the image link in the css.

```
#hero-container {
    background: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LwilPQw9Zc0/Unzm09oXDxI/AAAAAAAAHwo/30a7ZqSp3jE/s1600/blur-static+.jpg) no-repeat 50% fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I need the slide to show the image in the list item, i.e. the black image, see the css below.

```
.hero li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg');
}
```

Is this possible and can you provide and example by edition the fiddle?

Comment: I was just answering the last question. (you should probably change it so your question can't be answerable in 3 chars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this bit of code to change the background on click of the trigger element:

```
 $('#hero-container').css('background-image','url(http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg)');
```